# Are python strings can be mutable?

Tags: python, string, immutability

As string is immutable,so we can't change the string so how we can insert a character at middle position?

code:

```
s = "hello world"
s[5] = '-'
```

But it gives you error as it is immutable.so,how we can resolve this problem?

Comment: A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=are+python+strings+mutable) will give you your answer - no, strings are not mutable.

Answer (score 1):

We know string is immutable,but we can't change values through assignment operator.so we can acheive this through string slicing:

s = s[:5]+'-'+s[6:]

so now s becomes "hello-world".
so this can be done using string slicing.

Comment: But note that `s` is now a new string.  If `s` was passed as an argument to a function, the value of `s` in the function is now `hello-world`, but the caller still sees the original string `hello world`

Comment: @FrankYellin Then you should use global keyword inside function

Comment: That only helps if the caller also named their argument `s` and remembers to declare it `global.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the strings in the Python are immutable.
But we can perform concatenate operation on strings.

If we want to modify string like..

S = "Hello World"
S[5] = '-'

It is not possible but we can do this by slicing method

S = S[:5] + '-' + S[6:]
Then the result is
S = "Hello-World"